# How to set textarea scrollbar to right not with changing it's direction

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

I want to set  `<textarea>` scrollbar to right, but I don't want to change it's direction because the direction of the text inside it also changes.

Comment: Can we show the code you had trouble with please ?

Comment: What do you mean dude?! <textarea></textarea> is my code. by default it's scrollbar is on the left side. How to set it to the right?

Comment: Did you tryied something was the meaning of my sentence "show the code".

Comment: I think there is no way to control the side on which the scrollbar appears. For **rtl**, it'll always be on the left for most/all browsers.

Comment: For me it's default on the right side, maybe it's depended from the browser?

Comment: Of course, the whole document I'm using has been changed to the rtl direction because of the Persian Language which I'm using.

Answer (score 3):

Its a hack (did it just for the fun of it!) but you can hide the default scrollbar (on the left) and render a custom one yourself on the right.

*Note: 10 minute hack. Not really suitable for production code.*

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dkvvqz2u/3/

Code:

```
var textarea = $('textarea'), 
    scroller = $('<div/>').addClass('scroller').insertAfter(textarea),
    scroll = $('<div/>').addClass('scroll').appendTo(scroller);

// function to position the scroller correctly
function placeScroller() {

    scroller.css({
        top: textarea.offset().top + 'px',
        left: (textarea.offset().left + textarea.outerWidth() - 10) + 'px',
        height: textarea.outerHeight() + 'px'
    });

    scroll.css({
        top: Math.floor(textarea.scrollTop()/textarea[0].scrollHeight * textarea.outerHeight()) + 'px',
        left: '0',
        height: Math.floor(textarea.height()/textarea[0].scrollHeight * textarea.outerHeight()) + 'px'
    });
}

// place scroller initially.
placeScroller();

// update scroller on data change
textarea.on('scroll keyup paste cut undo', placeScroller);

// make mousewheel scrollable
textarea.on('wheel', function(_e) {
    textarea.scrollTop(textarea.scrollTop() + _e.originalEvent.deltaY);
    placeScroller();
});
```